# Configuration binding by using a public constructor with parameters

Tags: c#, .net, binding, asp.net-core-7.0

*My intention with this query is to obtain precise information whether a functionality is implemented or not in .Net 7.*

The problem: When we bind a class through its properties, we are unable to validate each field or property in such a way that we can guarantee the creation of an instance that ensures compliance with our restrictions or invariants.

For this reason I am interested in binding through the parameters of a public constructor. In this way, the initialization of each field or property will occur only in a private environment, by the constructor itself, and this would allow the validation of the parameters arrived at the constructor. Finally, we would have a consistent instance, or an exception.

A simple example:

```
public class SampleConfigClass
{
    public SampleConfigClass(string justAParameter)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(justAParameter))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(justAParameter), $"{nameof(JustAParameter)} cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        this.JustAParameter = justAParameter;
    }

    public string JustAParameter { get; private set; }
}
```

Here we have a class that would allow its properties to be initialized only in the private scope at the creation of the instance and to be accessed publicly.

Then using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` package we can perform the binding using:

```
var sampleConfigClass = builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SampleConfigClass)).Get<SampleConfigClass>();
```

Now, [I have read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-configuration-configurationbinder-get(microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfiguration-system-type-system-action((microsoft-extensions-configuration-binderoptions)))), and I can't find anywhere that initialization works through the constructor, in fact, I find many references in which it is said that initializing parameters through the constructor is not supported, however, if that out of that way my example code should not work and **it does work**. In fact, when I put a breakpoint in the constructor, it executes correctly. **So where is "this magic" coming from?**

I know that today we have OptionPattern and that we can apply validations to it, but I don't entirely agree with that flow. I don't like the idea of decoupling my validations or invariants from the instantiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation looks outdated. Binding using a single parametrized constructor which covers all public properties has been [implemented last year](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/67258), to support immutable types. For details, see [current `ConfigurationBinder` implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L470).

Comment: There it is! Thanks!